# PayPal integration on IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to do my app  with **PayPal** checkout, not a IAP.

I have some troubles with it, because this app for donations, I can't use webView that Paypal recommended.

I need do all checkouts in Safari. 
I can use SharedApplication to open URL in safari, but i don't have any ideas how to specify cancelURL and returnURL.

I know how to setup URLSchema to redirect urls to my application, but how to handle currently open url in safari - no ideas.

*I saw one app in appstore that works how i need
, so i think it is possible.*
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sport-relief-in-your-pocket/id498092260?mt=8

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: What kind of donations are we talking about? If you're expecting users to donate for use of the app itself, apple will reject it if you're avoiding IAP. If you're collecting for charity, they *might* let it pass...

Comment: and why can't you use a webview?

Comment: Donations to charities. I cant use webView because apple's guideline about charities must be done outside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you can do this by building your Donate button in Paypal and including the information in there.   The donate "button" is mostly a specially coded URL that includes the right information to drop you off on their site, so you can (using the Advanced area, section 4) add in the Cancel and success URLs.

Once you've finished putting the information into the forms, have it create the button, and then grab the "Email" version of the button, which will be relatively short, encoded, and not require forms.

You can then use that URL with SharedApplication to open the URL in Safari.